# Using theme for my Qt widget application

Tags: qt

How to use a theme for my in app/widget in qt embedded, I have follow the following instruction at this url. But it doesn't seem to work not sure why maybe i have missed something

[Qt dark orange stylesheet](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?2359-Release-Qt-dark-orange-stylesheet&p=14381&viewfull=1#post14381)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString file_path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/theme.css";

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QApplication::setStyle("plastique");

    MainWindow w;
    QFile style_file(file_path);
    if(style_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
      qDebug() << "Readin file OK!";
      w.setStyleSheet(style_file.readAll());
      style_file.close();
    }
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I also have upload the "theme.css" file to the same path, file do exists.

Comment: Try to give the absolute path

Comment: Check if it's finding the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to put the content of a stylesheet in [`QWidget::setStyleSheet`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop), not a path to a file. So open your file with `QFile`, read the contents and set that as your stylesheet.

Here is an example:

```
QFile style_file("path/to/stylesheet/darkorange.stylesheet");
if(style_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    this->setStyleSheet(style_file.readAll());
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but still not working see my modified question, ps I also have rename the stylesheet.

Comment: @Power-Mosfet *Not working* could mean anything. Be more specific. What fails? If the file opening fails, check the value of `file_path`.

Comment: thank you for the input, i just checked out the content of the theme file, its was an empty file i dont know but somehow i have overwritten it. I have replaced it with the correct file and guess what, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the absolute path to the stylesheet file:

```
QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + QString("darkorange.stylesheet");
```